# Visual Studio Unit Test - The member specified could not be found

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

Getting an odd problem with a unit test in my solution. One of the test always fails with the following error message:

> The member specified (BuildMap) could not be found. You might need to regenerate your private accessor,
>         or the member may be private and defined on a base class. If the latter is true, you need to pass the type
>         that defines the member into PrivateObject's constructor.

BuildMap is private and I have tried regenerating the accessor, changing it to public and recreating the unit test and it continuously fails. The other methods (both public and private) all work fine. BuildMap is also not defined in a base class.

Also tried all the usual things in case VS is messing about, restarting it, clean assemblies, rebuild etc...

Any ideas on the cause?

*update 1*: This is in Visual Studio 2008 or on the command line mstest tool.
*update 2*: Tried renaming the BuildMap method and the tests would not build stating it was missing. Appears that Visual Studio/MSBuild is doing the right thing, but somewhere between it and mstest it is breaking.

Comment: vs 2008? can you run the test from the command line?

Comment: Yip VS2008 - run from the command line produces the exact same errors.

Comment: had the same problem myself, and it turned out that during runtime it was using an older .dll of the code (it had the same assembly version). In that way the method didn't exist in the _Accessor as could be seen during debugging. Changing the assembly version or gacutil /if of the new .dll fixes the problem in my case

Comment: I have this same problem with a static, generic method in a console application.  Even deleting all bin and obj directories, as well as the result directories under TestResults, I can't get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough when I changed the method from static to not static the issue resolved itself. Other private static methods work fine though.
Still not sure of the cause but that is the resolution.